# $interval function only being called once in AngularJS app

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to write an application in Angular which updates data like every 10 seconds. My problem is that the function is only being called once every time i refresh my page.

The console.log is just to ensure that the function is just being called once.

This is my code for initiating the interval:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ngNotify', 'ngTagsInput', 'djds4rce.angular-socialshare']);

app.run(function($FB, $http, $rootScope, $interval){
  $FB.init('527807327395199');
  $interval(function() {callAtInterval($http, $rootScope)}, 1000, true);
  $rootScope.count = 0;
});


function callAtInterval($http, $rootScope) {
  $http.get("/points-for-school")
  .then(function(response){
    $rootScope.schoolCompetitionPoints = response.data;
    console.log($rootScope.count++);
    console.log(response);
  }, function(response){
    console.error(response);
  });
}
```

Is the problem that i do this in the app.run method?

Do i have to put the code into a controller for it to work?

If there is a way of making this work without creating a controller i would prefer it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem. The interval service can have four parameters:

```
$service(function, delay, count, invokeApply, pass)
```

The last three parameters is optional. The problem with my code was that the "true" parameter i sent in was read as count with the value 1 and therefore only executed the function once. There was two ways of solving this problem and: 1. remove the "true" parameter since it defaults it to true then.
2. specify that count is undefined

Here is the code i used to make it work:

```
app.run(function($FB, $http, $rootScope, $interval){
  $FB.init('527807327395199');
  $interval(function() { callAtInterval($http, $rootScope, undefined, true);}, 1000);
  $rootScope.count = 0;
});


function callAtInterval($http, $rootScope) {
  $http.get("/points-for-school")
  .then(function(response){
    $rootScope.schoolCompetitionPoints = response.data;
    console.log($rootScope.count++);
    console.log(response);
  }, function(response){
    console.error(response);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`$interval()` takes a function as argument, in order to call the function every 10 seconds.

But you're not passing a function as argument. You're **calling** `callAtInterval($http, $rootScope)`, and passing the value returned by this call (`undefined`) to `$interval()`. So you're effectively asking $interval to call `undefined` every 10 seconds.

What you actually want is

```
$interval(function() {
    callAtInterval($http, $rootScope);
}, 1000, true);
```

Comment: Yes that is true. I changed the code accordingly to what you proposed but the it is still only being called once.

Comment: You need to add the count parameter as well like i wrote in my answer. Thanks for the help though, it helped me get by the first problem with was how i passed in the function.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's late and possibly a few are interested. Probably JB Nizet was right in old version of angularjs. Now is necessary to pass as a paremeter number of times to repeat.

`$interval(function() {
       callAtInterval($http, $rootScope);
    }, 1000, 0, true);`

Parameter 0 will repeat indefinitely.

Here is [doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval).